# JavaScript statement to determine the first occurrence of a value within a string

Tags: javascript

What is the JavaScript statement that would be used to determine the position of the first slash / within the string variable "address" and assign that value to the "result" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method indexOf() returns the first occurrence of a given value within the string object. It returns -1 if the value isn't found.

```
var result = address.indexOf('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will tell index of first '/':

```
var a = 'asdasd/';
a.indexOf('/');
```

And this will tell last:

```
var a = 'asdasd/asfwerf/';
a.lastIndexOf('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code:
address.indexOf("/");